# Does the general solution for basin of attraction of polynomial 2-D differential equation exist?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I actually 'feel' that there does not, but can somebody link me to the paper that shows it? I have seen lots of papers introducing the method of estimating of basin of attraction, but I haven't seen any of them proving the (in)existences of exact solution for such basin of attraction. I`d like to get the simple proof or the link to the paper. Thank you for answering

Comment: So let me get this straight:  are you trying to find all basins of attraction for two-dimensional systems of the form $\dot x = P(x, y)$, $\dot y = Q(x, y)$ where $P(x, y), Q(x, y) \in \Bbb R[x, y]$, the ring of real polynomials in the two indeterminates $x$ and $y$?

Comment: @RobertLewis You got that right